# Usinstalling BricsCAD V15 on Ubuntu 14.04 is not possible?

Tags: internet, uninstall, removing, cad, bricscad

I have installed BricsCAD V15 from the internet as .deb and the USC helped to complete the installation, what ever I could not find it on the Synaptic Package Manager and I also can't uninstall it using the terminal because there is a space in the name "BricsCAD-**SPACE**-V15".

What should I do to uninstall it completely from my PC ?

if you didn't understand the question, I will clear up for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll have to find the CORRECT version of the Bricscad package, which may vary depending on your version.

```
dpkg-query -l b*
```

should find any package starting with b including bricscad.  You may have to search on B* as well to find it.

In my system it was then

```
 sudo dpkg -r bricscadv16
```

to remove the package.  This did not remove teh /Bricsys folder which you might have to do manually, but not before removing the package this may have consequences I can't predict.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to uninstall a single package file.deb you've downloaded and install is the command:

```
sudo dpkg -r package
```

Say you've downloaded the package BricsCAD-V15.2.11-1-en_US-amd64.deb and you'd like to uninstall it, then type in a terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -r BricsCad
```